# What happens to the cars produced in this factory?

Tags: grammar

I don't understand structure of that sentence:

*What happens to the cars produced in this factory?*

Why not: *What are the cars happen?*

All what I saw are: what [do] ... or what [have] or what [be].

Why in this sentence 'happens' follows after 'what'?

Comment: This is a subject question in which "what" is used as the subject. You only need a *do* when *what* is used as an object. "What do you need? ". Note that you explicitly use *what* as an object if you reverse the wh-fronting. "You need what? "

Comment: Perhaps my explanation is confusing. I'd rather you read [this](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/question-forms-subjectobject-questions)

Comment: By the way, do you know what the question is asking? A possible answer to "What happens to the cars" would be "They are sold in Europe," not "They drive fast." The question is not asking what the cars do; it is asking what someone will do to the cars.

Comment: @user178049, I liked your answer most of all. I'll approve it if you write it.

Comment: @user178049, I've found great example that helped me. "Who did Papa kiss?" vs "Who kissed Papa?"

Comment: @AlexeySubbota Oh yes, the wh-word is used as an obj :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is covered in Collins COBUILD English Grammar (Digital Edition) under the subtopic 
5.22 Wh-word

> *When a wh-word is the subject of a verb, or when it forms part of the subject,
>   **the word order of the clause is the same as that of a clause in the declarative**,
>   i.e. the subject is put first, followed by the verb.*
>
> (Emphasis mine)

This is what happens here, the wh-word (what) is used as the subject in your sentence so it follows the same order in a declarative sentence.

However, you need a *do-support* (if there's no auxiliary) when the wh-word is used as an object of a preposition or verb.

> What **do** you need?
>
> The wh-word (what) is used as object of the verb *need*. It will be clearer if your undo the wh-fronting. Like this
>
> You need **what**?

Answer (score 1):

This pattern

> What are the cars _________.

is a question form of the statement:

The cars are __________ what.

In that pattern, **what** is a direct object:

> What are the cars burning?  (that is, what kind of fuel?)
>
> The cars are burning diesel fuel.

Since **happen** is an intransitive verb, it does not take a direct object.  We cannot say:

> The cars are happen what. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

And since we cannot make that statement, neither can we ask the question

> What are the cars happen?  <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

To **happen** means 'to occur'.  An event occurs.  An action happens.

> Accidents happen.
>
> This car's door is dented! Something happened **to the car**.

The prepositional phrase **to the car** after **happened** expresses the idea "event occurred *having an effect on* the car".

Something happened which produced an effect on the car.

Something happened to the car.

> What happened to the car?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand structure of that sentence:

> What happens to the cars produced in this factory?
>
> Why not: What are the cars happen?

For he/she/it in the simple present tense, add 's' in the verb. But there isn't 3rd person singular in your sentence.